# How can I pull a report of effort by person in Azure DevOps under the Scrum template?

Tags: azure-devops, scrum

In Azure DevOps, I need to pull a report of the work done by person in order to distribute payments between team members.

Comment: Provide more info on requirement.
1. Is the person/user assigned to a team in project? Assignment is recommended
2. Do you need report alone or some other medium works fine.

Comment: Just want to check how's the things going? Is it succeed for you to use the below steps? Appreciate for [marking it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which will also helps others in the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the VSTS does not support [rollup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/support-rollup-of-work-and-other-fields?view=azure-devops) of the Effort directly:

[image]

I suggest you use query to pull out the report of effort for all teams first, then download this report and roll up the effort by person.

---

- **Step1:** Go **Query** page, then add **Effort** column by open **Columns Options**:

[image]

Note: This steps is very import, this can help for pull out a report which contains the Effort field.

- **Step2:** Create a query like below shown:

[image]

In the value of `State`, just input the states which represent the work done in your project. For me, there has 2 states can represent the work has been done: `Done` and `Closed`. For `Assign to`, you could specify the `group(s)` name which cover the all person you want to check in value blank.

- **Step3:** Download this into CSV by using the button `Export to CSV`:

[image]

- **Steps4:** The above step would generate a excel in local. Then you could apply the [**Pivot table**](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/how-to-create-pivot-table-tutorial-ht) into that to count the effort by
  person.